# How to get 'original' bytes of a Java String when read from DataOutputStream.writeUTF()?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, ascii

Currently I'm transferring a String across the network, using DataInput/OutputStream's. The String I am transferring needs to be converted into a byte array, to be decrypted.

However, since when the string was written using DataOutputStream.writeUTF("foobar"), its byte array contains encoded Java Modified UTF-8 data, which stuffs up the encryption process.

How can I get the original bytes from the Java modified UTF-8 String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode has several variants, where s-with-^ can either be one character or two: s plus combining-^. Java has a Normalizer class to convert to one specific variant.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html
or look immediately at the API.

This requires that the original string adheres to one variant. One cannot take bytes and then interprete them as UTF-8, because there are illegal sequences. This was done to prevent recognizing a wrong byte/character when in the middle of a byte sequence.

```
String normalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you write your string as byte[] and read it as byte[] using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(byte[], int, int)